# Haskell reverse function application operator not working

Tags: haskell

I'm playing around with Haskell, but I can't figure out why the reverse function application operator (&) is not working.

For example in ghci I get:

```
Prelude> "hello" & length

<interactive>:1:9: error:
    Variable not in scope: (&) :: [Char] -> ([a0] -> Int) -> t
```

When I expect it to return 5

Why is it not working?

Comment: It is in the `Data.Function` module, and not reimported in the `Prelude`, so you need to import it yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it's not in scope. [Asking Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts/hoogle?q=%26) tells me that you need to import it from, for example, `Data.Function`:

```
Prelude> import Data.Function
Prelude Data.Function> "hello" & length
5
```